# adding to a many to many relation django

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, models

Lets look at the django documentation code for adding members of the bettles.

First we have our models:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

now we have the code to add to the many to many relation:

```
# create a person named ringo
ringo = Person.objects.create(name="Ringo Starr")

# create a group named the beatles (terrible band so boring)

beatles = Group.objects.create(name="The Beatles")
>>> m1 = Membership(person=ringo, group=beatles,
...     date_joined=date(1962, 8, 16),
...     invite_reason="Needed a new drummer.")
>>> m1.save()
>>> beatles.members.all()
<QuerySet [<Person: Ringo Starr>]>

# what is this doing tho? 

 ringo.group_set.all()
<QuerySet [<Group: The Beatles>]>
```

as well do we need to just set the many to many relation like is done in the `Group` model?

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name
```

then go to the table that is holding all the foreign keys for the many to many relation and just add our saved objects?

```
m1 = Membership(person=ringo, group=beatles,
     date_joined=date(1962, 8, 16),
    invite_reason="Needed a new drummer.")
m1.save()
```

and then done?

We don't have to do any thing else with the

members `field` of the `Group` model?

## i.e this one?

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    # hes talking about me^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If so yay! But what is this thing all about?

```
ringo.group_set.all()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# what is this doing tho? 
ringo.group_set.all()
```

to understand it you can read the doc [related-objects-reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference) at the part of

> Both sides of a ManyToManyField relation: